# Install latest version compatible with selected framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

Is it possible to use NuGet to install the latest version that is compatible with my selected framework?

For example, if I try to install `Unity` via the Nuget Package Manager on a .NET 4.0 project it fails, as the latest version of Unity requires 4.5.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such feature.  You have to manually find the last compatible version and install that specific one with the `-Version` flag

Comment: I thought that might be the case.  It feel a little 'manual' for 2014 though, don't you think?

Comment: Yeah, and I feel the same about not being able to mark a package for only `-Safe` updates.

Comment: There is the filter by stable option and an `-AllVersions` and `-IncludePreReleases` flag you could append to the Get-Packages, [docs here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference).  Would that be of any help?

Answer (score 0):

Currently NuGet will not do this automatically for you. As jmoerdyk suggests you will need to find the Unity NuGet package that supports .NET 4.0 manually.

Probably the best way is to use the [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/). This application allows you to see different versions of the Unity package. Then you can open some of them and see what .NET frameworks they support by expanding the lib folder.

It looks like Unity 2.1.505.2 supports .NET 3.5 so that should work in your .NET 4.0 project. All the Unity v3 NuGet packages only support .NET 4.5.

Then you can install the Unity package using the Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Unity -Version 2.1.505.2
```